# Xamarin.Android ViewModelProvider without Factory

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to use `ViewModelProvider` on my Xamarin.Android project, there is no documentation about it on the Xamarin website so I looked for instructions on the android developer website. when I use it, an error occurs, does anyone know how to use a `ViewModelProvider` without using Factory

This is my code:

```
vm = new ViewModelProvider(this).Get(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(HomeViewModel))) as HomeViewModel;
```

Comment: I open the `ViewModelProvider` code. It have tree constructors, It seems that you need to set factory, Here is screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/mW51bkt

Comment: Here is an simple about ViewModel. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android-support-viewmodel/ But his used `ViewModelProviders.Of(this).Get(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ItemViewModel))) as ItemViewModel;` it is deprecated.